# Bash Script with Crontab

Tags: bash, text, cron

I'm trying to setup a crontab I have this in my current job in the current user I'm logged into

```
* * * * * /CS/day/get_info.sh
```

get_info.sh is supposed to output a text file every minute and I suspected that it would output a file in the same directory as the script is located but it doesn't.

I've also checked the syslogs to see if I could figure this out.

```
(user) CMD (/CS/day/get_info.sh)
(user) MAIL (mailed 46 bytes of output but got status  0x0001#012)
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`man cron` tells you:

> ```
>   When executing commands, any output is  mailed  to  the  owner  of  the
>   crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the
>   crontab, if such exists).  The children copies of  cron  running  these
>   processes  have their name coerced to uppercase, as will be seen in the
>   syslog and ps output.
> ```

So you have to

- `cd` into the appropriate directory yourself (cron will use `$HOME`)
- redirect *ANY* output to a file of your choice

You can do both things in the crontab. But I recommend to do it in the first lines of the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd WHEREEVER_YOU_WANT
exec > YOUR_LOG_FILE 2&>1
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is run in the home directory of the user and the file should be there as well. If you want it in the same directory as the script, either do a `cd` in your script or modify your crontab entry:

```
*/1 19-20 * * * cd /CS/day; /CS/day/get_info.sh
```

Another common problem with crontab entries is the environment. If the script works correctly in your terminal, try debugging it, when it is run from cron:

```
40 11 * * * bash -x /CS/day/get_info.sh >/tmp/get_info.sh.log 2>&1
```

Run it once only with current time, because otherwise you will overwrite your log file every minute.

Comment: I checked if the file would create in the home directory, and nothing was created with * * * * * /CS/date/get_info.sh

Answer (score 0):

On my case, I just had to install and configure an smtp client.